# insert + 1 in mysql n php

Tags: mysql, post

how i can insert with value + 1

```
      $id_agen = $_POST['id_agen'] + 1;
      $type = $_POST['type'];
      $harga = $_POST['harga'];
      $jenis = $_POST['jenis'];`enter code here`
      $count = count($_POST['harga']);
      for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_harga_agen (`id_agen`, `hrg_agen`, `type`,       `id_jenis` )VALUES('$id_agen[$i]' ,'$harga[$i]', '$type[$i]', '$jenis[$i]' )");
}
```

in line $id_agen, how can i do insert this

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: i want to $id agen + 1